# Unity3D global handler on instantiate and destroy game objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How I can subscribe on such events as instantiate or destroy any game objects on scene for accounting objects? It's required because FindObjectsOfType() is very slow operation.

Comment: I don't know of any builtin functionality for this.

Comment: You could provide your own static destroy/instantiate functions that track this for you, and call those exclusively. You could set up one or more components to register and deregister themselves during [`Awake()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html) and [`OnDestroy()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDestroy.html). Do you really need to track *every* GameObject? That's hard to believe.